# input expected at most 1 argument, got 2

Tags: python, input

whenever i try to run this it gives me the same input expected at most 1 argument, but got 2.

it definitely has something to do with

```
hole_int = int(input("Score on hole:", hole))
```

but i don't know what it is

[image]

Comment: `input` only takes one argument. You called it with two arguments.

Comment: What is the `hole` in `input` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

`input` only takes one argument. You called it with two arguments.

You're probably expecting it to work like `print`, which can take a bunch of arguments and print them one by one, separated by `sep` and followed by `end`. But those are special features of `print`, not general features that work for any function that can take a string.

If so, what you want to do is build a string, using concatenation, or, better, string formatting:

```
hole_int = int(input(f"Score on hole: {hole}"))
```

Comment: Good answer, but f string formatting isn't supported below 3.6 so I would provide a .format example as well.

Comment: @TheTesseract'sShadow I don’t think every answer needs to repeat the same “if you’re using 2.7 or 3.1-3.5, do this instead; if you’re using 2.6 or 3.0, do this instead; if you’re using 1.5-2.5, do this…” Most people are only one version behind at most, and if they’re not, they’ll usually say so. And future searchers with the same issue are even less likely to need an old version.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you would like to show the hole number in the input message.

You can use string formatting to do so:

```
hole_int = int(input("Score on hole: {}".format(hole)))
```